# Outlook REST API 2.0 roadmap / lifecycle

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

There are still several features that are not available in the Microsoft Graph API but are available in Outlook REST API v2.0 and beta versions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph-outlook). 
We would like to use these features but are concerned that the Outlook REST API will get deprecated soon and we invest time in something that won't be supported.

The documentation notes that its recommended to use the Microsoft Graph API but we could not find any page that reflects the Outlook REST API (v2.0, beta) roadmap / migration plan / the Outlook REST API lifecycle, 
can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked states that Outlook v2.0 is the same as Graph v1.0:

> The Microsoft Graph API offers two versions: v1.0 and beta, while Outlook offers v1.0, v2.0, and beta. Microsoft Graph v1.0 matches Outlook v2.0, and Microsoft Graph beta matches Outlook beta. The Outlook v1.0 version is being deprecated.

So you should just be able to use Graph. Do you have an example of a feature in Outlook v2.0 that's not in Graph v1.0?

Comment: Following is the comparison: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/compare-graph-outlook yes you are right, but still iys interesting for me to know when Microsoft will deprecate Outlook REST api, im pretty sure they wont support 2 apis..

Comment: You can see in the comparison link there is a Feature Difference section

Comment: I see what you mean - my recommendation then would be to use the feedback link on that page to file a bug on GitHub asking for clarification on life cycle and timelines.